# How to create a bar plot with an x-variable with three levels and an unrelated dichotomous y-variable in proportions

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, bar-chart

Example Table:

| Obesity and/or Diabetes status | Death occurred |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 0 | 0 |

I want to create a bar graph where the x-variable is the obesity and/or diabetes status and where there will be three adjacent bars for 0, 1, and 2. I want the y-variable to be the proportion of individuals in each x category that have died. The code that I attempted to run is as follows:

```
install.packages("qdap", "dplyr", "tidyr", "ggplot2")
install.packages("igraph", type = "binary")
install.packages("gender", type = "binary")
library(qdap)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

`FramFinal2017(1)`$category <- rownames(`FramFinal2017(1)`)

df <- `FramFinal2017(1)` %>%
      gather(results, DEATH, - category) %>%
      mutate(results = char2end(results, "_", 2)) %>%
      separate(category, c("category", "Response"))

ggplot(data = df, aes(x = category, y = DEATH, fill = Response)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "stack") +
    facet_grid(. ~ results)
```

But the code keeps spitting out errors related to the packages themselves, such as :

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘qdap’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]): namespace ‘dplyr’ 0.8.3 is already loaded, but >= 0.8.5 is required
```

Please let me know if there is another way to do this problem or if you need more clarification.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
library(tidyverse)
read.table(text="status Death
0   1
2   1
1   0
2   0
2   0
1   1
0   0", header=T) %>% 
  group_by(status)  %>%
   summarise(total = n(),
             n=sum(Death)) %>% 
  mutate(proportion_death = n/total*100) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(status, proportion_death)) + 
   geom_col()
```

[image]